# Android WebView.postUrl() showing blank screen when posting to HTTPS URL

Tags: android, https, httpclient, android-webview

In my android app, I am posting data to a `https` servlet URL from a `WebView` as shown below

```
String postData = "fileContents=" + fileCon;
WebView.postUrl(url, EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "BASE64"));
```

The URL in the above code is a servlet URL for which I have to post some data and from there I am redirecting to some other URL.

The above code worked fine when the servlet URL is just `HTTP`. But when changed to `HTTPS`, it is showing a blank screen.

I tried the following solution for android `HTTPS` problem:
http://blog.antoine.li/index.php/2010/10/android-trusting-ssl-certificates/

I removed the above code from `onCreate()` method and tried the following code

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fileContents", fileCon));
DefaultHttpClient client = new MyHttpClient(getApplicationContext());
try {   
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
    UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
    request.setEntity(formEntity);
    HttpResponse resp = client.execute(request);
} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now I am able to post the data and from there it is redirecting also. But still I am seeing a blank screen.

Is it because I don't have either `loadUrl` or a `postUrl` I am seeing a blank screen?

Or should I put the above code in any method of `WebView`?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10970539/1008278

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fileContents", fileCon));
    DefaultHttpClient client = new MyHttpClient(getApplicationContext());
try {   
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
    UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
    request.setEntity(formEntity);
    HttpResponse resp = client.execute(request);

    //Get data
     HttpEntity entity = resp.getEntity();
     InputStream is = entity.getContent();
     String data = convertStreamToString(is);
     browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
     browser.loadData(data,"text/html", "UTF-8");
} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

InputStream to String method:

```
private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

String line = null;
try {
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append((line + "\n"));
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
return sb.toString();
```

}